# stem and leaf plot in R wrong '|' position

Tags: r, plot

I have a list of integers `x1` within 80 and 100.

`x=round(runif(100, min=80, max=100))`
 [image: X1]

However when I try to plot the stem and leaf plot. It seems R treats them as 91.0, 81.0 etc..

`stem(x)`

[image: x2]

The desired output should be only one number on the left.
[image: desired output]

I have tried `stem(x1/10)`, `stem(x1, scale=1/2/3)` and `stem(trunc(x1))` But none of them worked.

Comment: please avoid adding screenshot of code, and instead copy the code itself that we will be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** an issue of integer vs. double. The issue is that the range of values is too small to create a big enough stem-and-leaf plot with the second digit.

You can simply change the tolerance to get the result you want, by simply passing a value for `atom`:

```
stem(x1,atom=10)
```

The output is:

```
  The decimal point is 1 digit(s) to the right of the |

   8 | 0000111122222333444
   8 | 555666666777778888999999999
   9 | 000111122223333444444
   9 | 55556666666677777788888999999
  10 | 0000
```